Issues connecting to SMTP server
I'm encountering the error below when trying to register a new user on a Laravel project:

Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "boss@gmail.com"
using 3 possible authenticators. Authenticator LOGIN returned Expected
response code 235 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8
Username and Password not accepted. For more information, go to\r\n535
5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials e18-20020a63d952000000b005e838955bc4sm6695454pgj.58 - gsmtp\r\n".
Authenticator PLAIN returned Expected response code 235 but got code
"535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted.
For more information, go to\r\n535 5.7.8
https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials
e18-20020a63d952000000b005e838955bc4sm6695454pgj.58 - gsmtp\r\n".
Authenticator XOAUTH2 returned Expected response code 250 but got code
"535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted.
For more information, go to\r\n535 5.7.8
https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials
e18-20020a63d952000000b005e838955bc4sm6695454pgj.58 - gsmtp\r\n\

A verification code should have been sent to the email of the new user.
